# Placing ten people on a round table with certain conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> Ten people sit at a round table where $5$ them eats bread and $5$ them doesn’t. They will take their seats such that no two persons eating bread will sit next to each other and no two persons not eating bread will sit next to each other. In how many possible ways they can be seated? (Seats are not unique)

Since the seats are not unique we can sit $10$ people in $9!$ different ways. Now, is this just $\binom{9}{5}=126$ since we need to in how many ways we can sit the $5$ people eating bread as the people not eating bread will also be in the configuration where none of them sits next to each other?

Comment: Let's mark positions with people eating bread as 1,3,5,7,9. We can sit 5 people in these positions in $5!$ ways. We can sit 5 other people in $5!$ ways. We can select 1 position in 5 ways. So the result is $5!^2 / 5=5!\cdot 4!$.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "seats are not unique" ?

Comment: I mean that it doesn’t matter if we ”shift” the seating arrangement as long as the same people sit next to each other. @G.Fougeron

Comment: Rather than saying seats are not unique, you could say that two seating arrangements which can be obtained from one another by rotation are considered equivalent.  However, that is the usual convention for circular permutation problems.

Comment: OK, in this case, I think @IvanKaznacheyeu 's response is complete :-). Do you have trouble understanding it ?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Beat me to it.  I think that your response deserves to be posted as an answer.